# 12.04 LTS and nvidia-current don't work

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

Recently, an automatic security update upgraded my Nvidia driver to "version current". Upon restart, I have a **blank**, but otherwise functional logon screen and desktop screen. By that, I mean the screen is black, but you can "use" the computer exactly as if the monitor was turned off. Purging and reinstalling the driver doesn't remedy things.

The video card is a GeForce 9800 GT, which *should* be supported by the current Nvidia driver. I'd prefer to figure out why they don't work and fix that, but at this point I'd be willing to downgrade to a version I know for sure works, which is no longer offered in the Additional Drivers window.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/279702/nvidia-driver-update-error

Answer (score 0):

I recovered by installing the backport of the Quantal kernel and X11 plus the `nvidia-current` package and then deleting my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.  If you  want to go that route I would take backups of anything you consider worth holding onto.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-quantal xserver-xorg-lts-quantal
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf-$(date '+%Y%m%d')
sudo reboot
```

Some details of the result:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
$ uname -rvp
3.5.0-27-generic #46~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 26 19:33:56 UTC 2013 i686
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 210] [10de:0a65] (rev a2)
```

My dmesg (recorded to /var/log/syslog) is still receiving a stream of these but the X session looks alright.

```
[  580.545981] [drm:drm_edid_block_valid] *ERROR* EDID checksum is invalid, remainder is 128
[  580.545984] Raw EDID:
[  580.545986]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545988]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545990]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545993]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545995]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545997]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.545999]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.546002]      ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[  580.546008] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DVI-I-1: Ignoring invalid EDID block 1.
```

If I had tried downgrading that would leave me with security flaw:

```
- CVE-2013-0131:
  NVIDIA UNIX GPU Driver ARGB Cursor Buffer Overflow in
  "NoScanout" Mode. This buffer overflow, which occurred
  when an X client installed a large ARGB cursor on an
  X server running in NoScanout mode, could cause a denial
  of service (e.g., an X server segmentation fault), or
  could be exploited to achieve arbitrary code execution.
```

Update: turns out I'm now running the open-source Nouveau drivers now.  They didn't work for me in the past but the ones they have now are able to detect the modeline for my monitor despite the warning about EDID.